# How to get current frame, using FFMpeg

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I have successfully compiled the FFMPEG library to android using NDK. 
I want to create a method to get the current frame, how I can do this?

Comment: Please tell me step by step how to install and use FFMPEG in android. It's urgent

Comment: This is old question, what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Can get Current timestamp!!))

```
    AVPacket        packet;  
...
    av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet);
...
    packet->pts;
```